# How do I stop service fabric application upgrade?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How do I stop Azure Service Fabric compose application upgrade which is failing and never timing out?

Upgrade details below which does not have timeout set. I know what the issue with application is (no registry username/password specified) but I can not cancel current upgrade.

```
UPGRADE DETAILS
Name    fabric:/planet
Type Name   Compose_5
Target Application Type Version v7
Upgrade Domains
Name    State
UD0 InProgress
UD1 Pending
UD2 Pending
Upgrade State   RollingForwardInProgress
Next Upgrade Domain UD1
Rolling Upgrade Mode    UnmonitoredAuto
Upgrade Description
Name    fabric:/planet
Target Application Type Version v7
Upgrade Kind    Rolling
Rolling Upgrade Mode    UnmonitoredAuto
Upgrade Replica Set Check Timeout In Seconds    4294967295
Force Restart   false
Monitoring Policy
Failure Action  Manual
Health Check Wait Duration  0.00:00:00.0
Health Check Stable Duration    0.00:02:00.0
Health Check Retry Timeout  0.00:10:00.0
Upgrade Timeout Infinity
Upgrade Domain Timeout  Infinity
Upgrade Duration    0.00:21:01.241.0700000000652
Upgrade Domain Duration 0.00:21:01.241.0700000000652
Current Upgrade Domain Progress
Domain Name UD0
Node Upgrade Progress List
Node Name   Upgrade Phase   Pending Safety Checks
CONTAINERHOST1  Upgrading   (empty)
Start Timestamp Utc Fri, 03 Aug 2018 02:20:34 GMT
Failure Timestamp Utc   N/A
Failure Reason  None
```

Comment: Try Start-ServiceFabricApplicationRollback

Comment: Does not work since it's `compose` application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you've set the failure mode to manual, the cluster will be stuck waiting your action.

You could try Start-ServiceFabricApplicationRollback  or Resume-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade to continue.

The recomended approach to upgrade a compose is using the parameters `-Monitored -FailureAction Rollback`

```
Start-ServiceFabricComposeDeploymentUpgrade -DeploymentName mydeployment -Compose docker-compose.yml -Monitored -FailureAction Rollback
-Monitored -FailureAction Rollback
```

Unless it was expected to do this manual intervention, Service Fabric should handle it by itself if the upgrade parameters are configure correctly.

Fixing these settings might solve your problem:

**`Rolling Upgrade Mode`** is set to *UnmonitoredAuto*, it automate the upgrade and failure check but does not do HealthCheck. Consider using *Monitored*

**`Upgrade Domain Timeout`** and **`Upgrade Timeout`** are set to *Infinity*,
they should have a timeout set, otherwise it will wait forever.

**`Failure Action`** is set to *manual*, the upgrade is being suspended to allow you to investigate the deployment before taking any further action. Consider using *Rollback* instead.

You might have to configure other parameters as well. To understand these parameters, take a look in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-parameters) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-visualstudio-configure-upgrade).
For compose deployment, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-docker-compose):

Comment: This is `compose` application and `Start-ServiceFabricApplicationRollback` does not work on it. Error is `Start-ServiceFabricApplicationRollback : Invalid operation on Compose defined application. Use corresponding operation.`

Answer (score 4):

You can change the Upgrade Domain Timeout and the Upgrade Timeout of a running upgrade by invoking the [Update-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/update-servicefabricapplicationupgrade?view=azureservicefabricps) command in a Service Fabric Powershell task.

```sh
Update-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName fabric:/MyApp -UpgradeTimeoutSec 900 -UpgradeDomainTimeoutSec 700
```